# how to download files within a range with curl, and assign custom file names?

Tags: curl

So I'm attempting to download a bunch of files with the following command:

```
curl -O http://example.com/[1-100]/test.json
```

It would save all the files as test.json, is there any way of specifying a dynamic filename for each file in the range?

Thanks!

Jason

Answer (score 5):

According to docs: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

> -o, --output
>
> Write output to  instead of stdout. If you are using {} or [] to fetch multiple documents, you can use '#' followed by a number in the  specifier. That variable will be replaced with the current string for the URL being fetched.

so you can combine custom filename for new file using `#n` placeholder

```
curl http://example.com/[1-100]/test.json -o response_#1.json
```

where in `#1` curl will place current iterator

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
  curl -o "test.$i.json" "http://example.com/$i/test.json"
done
```

The curl man page is pretty extensive, it has all kinds of options. You can check it out at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: Thanks! However, according to this line in the man page: "curl will attempt to re-use connections for multiple file transfers, so that getting many files from the same server will not do multiple connects / handshakes. This improves speed. Of course this is only done on files specified on a single command line and cannot be used between separate curl invokes.", it reuses connection if you do it in one go, but won't do the optimization if using multiple commands. That's mostly why I was asking if there is a way using a single command